# How to salute at team-match end?

Tags: hawken

How do you salute (bow to) the other players when you finish (and win) any Team Match game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be describing a **Mech Emote**. The default key is `J`, but you can of course change it in settings->key bindings. You can also perform your mech emote during the match, although it might be *tactically unwise* to do so when enemies are around.

You can select the mech emote for each of your mechs in garage->cosmetics. Per default, there is one emote available for each mech size-class. The emote you mentioned sounds like the default emote of the light mech ("the pleasure was all mine") or medium mech ("that just happened"). More animations for each mech-class can be unlocked for 356 Meteor Credits each.